# Is browser() required to single step through an if block or for loop in the main program in Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Is it true that in rstudio I can't single step through an if block or for loop in the main program without invoking browser() or some other debugging method?

I tend to work out of a large source file that contains a lot more than just the "production" code.

I expected to be able to single step through an if block.  Apparently I need to insert a browser() statement and source the whole active document.  This is inconvenient for me as the active document is a sprawling collection of examples, snippets, tests, memorabilia, and jokes along with the "production" region of the code.

Comment: One way in R (regardless of the RStudio IDE) to step through code like that is by using `browser()`. RStudio adds the ability with `Shift-F9` to toggle a breakpoint, which is very very similar (you don't see `browser()` since I believe it's using `trace(...)` instead). The IDE "Debug" menu seems mostly self-explanatory.

Comment: I don't understand, though, why is adding a `browser()` expression so onerous? If you want to debug one function within the vast forest of files/functions, I find `debug(funcname)` or even `debugonce(funcname)` to be helpful, allowing you to skip past what you assume is working-code.

Comment: *"and source the whole active document"* I don't know where this is coming from. I just put a line `print("try not to run this")` followed by a `for` loop and put `browser()` in the loop. Run the loop, browser works fine, the previous line isn't run. In RStudio you can also run one (expression) line at a time with ctrl/cmd + Enter. I'll often debug by setting the loop index directly in my console (e.g., `i = 1`) and then step through the loop one line at a time, just skipping the actual `for(...)` invocation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So the answer to the question as posted is "Yes"?